# didSelectRowAtIndexPath performSegueWithIdentifier = i get nil in target view

Tags: ios, swift

i have ThirdView in my "start" view

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

class ThirdView : UITableViewController {

var jsonz:NSArray = ["Ray Wenderlich"];
   var valueToPass : String?;
   var programVar : String?;

override func viewDidLoad() {

    super.viewDidLoad() 
}

override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject!) {

    var newProgramVar = "lol";

    let destinationVC = segue.destinationViewController as! FourthView
    destinationVC.programVar = newProgramVar
} 

override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1;
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

    return self.jsonz.count;
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let myCell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! UITableViewCell

    myCell.textLabel?.text = self.jsonz[indexPath.row] as? String;
    return myCell;
}
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

    let valueToPass = "asd";
    let destinationVC = FourthView()
    destinationVC.valuePassed = valueToPass;

    self.performSegueWithIdentifier("restDetail", sender: tableView);
}
}
```

I have a segue identifier: restDetail
[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/6SMtS.png]

When i run a project and click on cell, i cant recieve a variable **valuePassed** in "second" view, i get nil. Please help, why?
But i normal recieve a variable **programVar** from function prepareForSegue, it is ok. I have only problem with didSelectRowAtIndexPath segue.

It is my FourthView:

```
import UIKit

class FourthView: UIViewController {


var valuePassed:String!
var programVar:String!

override func viewDidLoad() {


    super.viewDidLoad()
    println(valuePassed);
    println(programVar);


    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


}
```

See here what i have in output:

```
nil
lol
nil
lol
```

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/wbHfm.png]

And second question: why in output it shows 4 times?
Sorry for my english.

Comment: for somebody, who have same problem, see what you need add to prepareForSegue() function (in my example): `let indexPath:NSIndexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow()!` and then you can use your indexPath in prepareForSegue functions, for example what i used: `destinationVC.name = self.jsonz[indexPath.row] as? String;` . In FourthView i declare String **name** and it is ok sended.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` you are not initializing the FourthView instance correctly.

This line:

`let destinationVC = FourthView()`

Creates a random instance of `FourthView`, that isn't the one you're using as destination.
If you want to pass a value to the FourthView it's usually best to do that in `prepareForSegue`.

As you can see in the line below, here you are setting the destinationVC variable to FourthView instance, which is the destination View Controller of your segue.

`let destinationVC = segue.destinationViewController as! FourthView`

Answer (score 0):

The issue is with the following code:

```
let valueToPass = "asd";
let destinationVC = FourthView()
destinationVC.valuePassed = valueToPass;
```

You are allocating a temporary instance of `FourthView` and passing data to it. And after that you perform a segue. Perform segue initialises your view controller and loads it to the view (different one, not the one you initialised manually in the `didSelectRowAtIndexPath`). You need to pass the data from the `prepareForSegue:` method.